# Are data.tables stored twice in ReferenceClass objects?

Tags: r, data.table

I do not know if this is just an odd behavior of `data.table::tables()` or if this is maybe a problem:

```
library(data.table)
TestClass <- setRefClass(  
  Class  = "TestClass",  
  fields = list(
    dt = "data.table"
  ),
  methods = list(
    setTable = function( rows ){
      dt <<- data.table( a = seq_len(rows), b = seq_len(rows) )
    }
  )
)

tc <- TestClass$new()
tc$setTable( rows = 1E7 )
```

When I look at the memory consumption, I'll get

```
tables( env=tc )
     NAME        NROW MB COLS KEY
[1,] .->dt 10,000,000 77 a,b     
[2,] dt    10,000,000 77 a,b     
Total: 154MB
```

Does this mean, that the `data.table` really consumes twice the amount of memory than necessary?

Comment: Just check `address(tc$dt)` and `address(tc$\`.->dt\`)`. This report is not specific to ref class. `DT <- data.table(x=1:1e7, y=1:1e7); bla=DT; tables()`

Comment: @Arun, didn't know about `address()`. Thank you! Now what shall I do with the question, since I'm not expecting a proper answer anymore? Is it worth keeping it?

Comment: Beasterfield, `address` is just a nice little utility function in `data.table`. IMHO, you can answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply no:

```
address(tc$dt) == address(tc$`.->dt`)
[1] TRUE
```

Credit for this goes to @Arun (see his comment below my question).